# Can I connect to several Kubernetes clusters simultaneously - each in different terminal session?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have 4 kubernetes clusters I need to switch between to check or monitor - sometimes I quickly need to switch back and forth between them.

I see that the kubectl config context is 1 file for the user so if I have 10 terminal windows opened, they will all point to just 1 kubernetes cluster.

Is there a way to have a terminal session in which to maintain the kubernetes context, regardless of what k8s/kubectl context I use in my other terminal session.

I am using either Windows Terminal or bash on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

Try checking out [this page in the docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/#set-the-kubeconfig-environment-variable), the $KUBECONFIG env variable is easy to manage in different sessions.

As for managing a workspace with multiple sessions - I recommend [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/Getting-Started).
It takes a while to get used to, but it allows you to describe your sessions and their environments (you can use `send-keys 'export KUBECONFIG=/kubeconfig/for/one/cluster'` inside tmux) in a bash script and have different panes export different $KUBECONFIG paths